# MongoDB Aggregation: How to find cost of remaining stocks

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I want to find out how much cost I have in remaining stocks.
It should filter out stock with remaining = 0

I have the following data

```
db={
  stocks: [
    {
      remaining: 2,
      costPerItem: 5
    },
    {
      remaining: 3,
      costPerItem: 2
    },
    {
      remaining: 0,
      costPerItem: 3
    }
  ]
}
```

I have created Mongo Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/d5S19t60V4B

Total cash of each item is `remaining * costPerItem`

The expected result should return total cash in stock: 16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group all documents, and sum the total of the result multiplying the `remaining` and `costPerItem` values.

```
db.stocks.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      totalCashInStock: {
        $sum: {
          $multiply: [
            "$remaining",
            "$costPerItem"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-phwFfnQPl7)

You could add a `$match` stage before the `$group` stage to filter the document with `remaining` not 0. It is optional as if `remaining` is 0, the outcome after multiplying with `costPerItem` will be 0, so *technically* the result will be the same as the aggregation query without the `$match` stage.

**Updated**: In case there is a document with negative `remaining` value, then the `$match` stage is required for the accurate calculation.

Comment: Can you share the complete code?

Comment: I fixed it. It's because it conflict my route declaration.
I have @Get('/:id') declared before @Get('/totalCashInStock')

Comment: Btw, I need $match because sometimes remaining could be negative. But I cannot get $match to work. Here is mongo playground https://mongoplayground.net/p/eK-UGFkImI-

Comment: Ya, agree, for this case, a `$match` stage is required. =)

Comment: It works now https://mongoplayground.net/p/0Fr-WULs5Jd
Thank you